# How many max number of relationships can be placed on single Entity Node in Spring Data Neo4j?

Tags: java, spring-boot, neo4j, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-neo4j

We have a Member node and it is having relationships with 9 other nodes. Between each Member and one of each node from 9 other end nodes there will be 100+ relationships with different countries. see the data l like below

```
(:Member)-[:ORDER_USA]->(:Order)
(:Member)-[:ORDER_IND]->(:Order)
(:Member)-[:ORDER_ARE]->(:Order)
..... like this for 100+ countries

(:Member)-[:ORDERHISTORY_USA]->(:OrderHistory)
(:Member)-[:ORDERHISTORY_IND]->(:OrderHistory)
(:Member)-[:ORDERHISTORY_ARE]->(:OrderHistory)
..... like this for 100+ countries

(:Member)-[:ADJUSTMENT_USA]->(:Adjustment)
(:Member)-[:ADJUSTMENT_IND]->(:Adjustment)
(:Member)-[:ADJUSTMENT_ARE]->(:Adjustment)
..... like this for 100+ countries
```

As above, Order, OrderHistory, Adjustment... Member having relationships with countries with 6 other Nodes. So, the total @Relationships on the Java @NodeEntity class is more than 900+.

Please help me on how to handle this in Java program using Spring Data Neo4j JPA.

Comment: Why do you have different edge _types_ for the different countries?

Comment: Your data model seems all wrong. What are your use cases (what are you trying to achieve with your data), and why is such importance being placed on identifying countries?

Comment: There are multiple reports there in my system, those are all specific to country. Finally, I need to calculate the accumulated sum at world wide.